# what is identifier expecting error

Tags: java

What is *identifier expected error*?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  class MyClass {

  public static void fizzBuzz(Integer)
  {
    int x=0,n;
    System.out.println("give any number");
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = Scan.nextInt();
    for(x=0;n<x;x++)
    {
        if(x==3)
        {
            System.out.println("fizz");
            x=x+1;
        }
        else if(x==5)
        {
            System.out.println("buzz");
            x=x+1;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("x");
            x=x+1;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

**error**

```
user_file.java:5: error: <identifier> expected
    public static void fizzBuzz(Integer)
                                       ^
```

Comment: The error literally points to where the problem is and tells you what is missing. What is the name, the identifier, of the method parameter?

Comment: In this case, you really are missing an identifier.  In general, however, "identifier expected" errors can be generated on many kinds of syntax errors, so in the future, don't take the message too literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes

1.)  You should have if not done already `public static void main(String[] args) { // call your method here}`

2.) `n` is declared twice.

3.) `public static void fizzBuzz(Integer)` is wrong, variable name is missing.

change to `public static void fizzBuzz(Integer a)`

`int x=0,n;` and   `int n = Scan.nextInt();`

Comment: ummm, you don't know that this is supposed to be the main program, do you?  And he probably can't put a `main` in `MyClass` since the class is not named the same as his source file.

Answer (score 1):

Here `public static void fizzBuzz(Integer)`
You have given only Type  Integer not the variable which will hold Integer type value.

`public static void fizzBuzz(Integer)`

app a variable like code below
`public static void fizzBuzz(Integer z)`

You have declared n tow time  int x=0,n; and at  `int n = Scan.nextInt();`

remove int from second declation.